# Base X string encoding

Tags: algorithm, encoding

I'm looking for a routine that will encode a string (stream of bytes) into an arbitrary base/alphabet (like base64 encoding but I get to choose the alphabet). I've seen a few routines that do base X encoding for a number, but not for a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encode/decode a long to a string using a fixed set of letters in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938482/encode-decode-a-long-to-a-string-using-a-fixed-set-of-letters-in-java)

Comment: See also, in java, for `String` input, with `BigInteger` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863954/substitution-cypher-with-different-alphabet-length/

Comment: Not a duplicate, both solutions linked above use numbers and wouldn't do for longer inputs.
This is a really interesting challenge, and I think I may have a solution. Let me work on a proof-of-concept.

Answer (score 3):

There is my implementation of BaseX (BaseN) encoding algorithm: https://github.com/KvanTTT/BaseNcoding.

Also you can experiment with different alphabets and parameters at demo-site: http://kvanttt.github.io/BaseNcoding/

Answer (score 1):

Every algorithm I've seen (and written) for this has a sequence of characters, and does a divmod of the number by the length of the sequence, uses the mod for the index into the sequence for the digit character, and feeds the div back into the process.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a sample of this in python or ruby?  For example, I want to base36 encode a string.

Comment: @Bradford: Well, which part of the implementation are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have this ruby script I'm trying to write, but am stuck trying to Base36 encode the encrypted value.  I posted the problem on SO earlier today [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035755/base36-des-unique-ids-in-ruby).  I can base36 encode a number just fine.  My problem is the encrypted value is not a digest.  Maybe I screwed that up some how.