# Generating Alphanumeric OTP using HOTP

Tags: cryptography, hmac, hmacsha1

I understand that HOTP can be used to create numerical One Time Passwords. The algorithm behind being:

> K be a secret key 
>   C be a counter
>   HMAC(K,C) = SHA1(K ⊕ 0x5c5c… ∥ SHA1(K ⊕ 0x3636… ∥ C)) with ⊕ as XOR, ∥ as concatenation, (C is the message)

Truncate be a function that selects 4 bytes from the result of the HMAC in a defined manner.

Then HOTP(K,C) is mathematically defined by:

> HOTP(K,C) = Truncate(HMAC(K,C)) & 0x7FFFFFFF

I have used the following example implementation for my tests and it works fine:

https://svn.forgerock.org/openam/tags/10.0.0-docs/products/amserver/source/com/sun/identity/authentication/modules/hotp/HOTPAlgorithm.java

My question is that is it possible to generate an alphanumeric OTP using HOTP instead of numeric. The advantage obviously being that the strength of OTP increases manyfold for a given length. So a 8 digit alphanumeric code is far stringer than an eight-digit numeric code.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can do whatever you want after the HMAC(K,C). You can map it to HEX or to alphanumeric.

But then you would also have to create your own OTP token - either a hardware token or a smartphone app.
This is the great thing about standards, that you do not have to create your own! ;-)

Comment: Thanks cornelinux, Good to know it can be done. Could you please give me a little more direction to as in HOW it can be done. My SHA1 returns a 20 byte value (-127 to 127). How can I make it a alphanumeric value?

Comment: First you should decide, what characters you want to use. Thus you get a list of maybe (26 + 26 +10 = 56 possible characters). Then you probably should map one byte to the character...

Comment: ok, so I need to map my 256 possible byte combinations from the HMAC to the 62 possible character set. That basically means that 4 bytes from my 256 byte set will correspond to 1 byte from my 62 byte output set. This can be easily done, but do you think this reduces the security/strength of HOTP in nay way?

Comment: No I don't think so. HOTP reduces to 4 byte output (a number between within 1.000.000).

Answer (score 1):

Alphanumeric has a tricky base, base 62. If you allow two more characters then you can just use base 64 (replacing the `+` and `/` with any value you prefer).

Otherwise, just look up a Base N encoding library, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065206/base-x-string-encoding) for Java (didn't try it, cannot comment on correctness or performance).

This won't influence the security as there is a 1:1 relation between the generated HOTP bits and the given representation. In other words, the different base representation and alphabet are just a different *view* on the same bit values.