# LoggerFactory ArrayUtils Random

Tags: java, string, encode, utf, alphabet

this one does not fly for me:
http://pastebin.com/Mctnidng
It was elaborated in this forum under a different thread. I've divided it into two files

```
AlphabetHelper.java

AlphabetHelperTest.java 



java  -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)

javac  -version
javac 1.6.0_18
```

on attempt to compile I included some

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.List;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
```

But it does not take of. I assume there must be some other Java distribution out there, apache or android. The code however looks quite good, how can I get to run on my Java 1.6? Most oder Java sourcode works fine on my machine.

```
javac  -Xlint  AlphabetHelper.java
AlphabetHelper.java:41: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable ArrayUtils
location: class AlphabetHelper
                ArrayUtils.toObject(
                ^

javac -Xlint  AlphabetHelperTest.java
AlphabetHelperTest.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Random
location: class AlphabetHelperTest
    private Random random;
            ^

AlphabetHelperTest.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Logger
location: class AlphabetHelperTest
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AlphabetHelperTest.class);
                         ^
```

it is all about this file   http://pastebin.com/Mctnidng    to be compiled tested and deployed on Java 1.6

Sincerely,

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the problem is. What is happening that you don't like? The compiler errors? Please provide more information.

Comment: The file in the link has no imports at all.  When you compile that code, are you using the imports above?  Also, I don't see "ArrayUtils" imported anywhere.  It's not a standard rt.jar class.

Comment: I created two files: AlphabetHelper.java  AlphabetHelperTest.java  and imported the most likely needed imports. After asking on IRC they told me most likely it was a different distribution than OpenJDK or the to me known stable JDK. ArrayUtils.toObject()  was reported to be a non JDK class. 

import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils; could be useful, but I've never done such an import. I think it may be the solution, but then it is no more java as defined by sun. It was discussed in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863954 and reported as a solution, which I am now examining.